Values don't persist with "display: none"
I have 2 forms
 const Form1 = () => (
    <form style={{ display: activeStep === 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
      <label>Form1</label>
      <input size={10}></input>
      <ButtonDefaultLink name='MoveNext' className='' click={()=>{setActiveStep(prev=>prev+1)}}/>
    </form>
  );

  const Form2 = () => (
    <form style={{ display: activeStep === 1 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
      <label>Form2</label>
      <input size={10}></input>
      <ButtonDefaultLink name='MoveNext' className='' click={()=>{setActiveStep(prev=>prev+1)}}/>
    </form>
  );

I hide unhide them based on state variable. My expectation was that as I am not doing activestep==1 && <Form1/> and instead playing wih CSS property, the form values will persist. But when I enter some text, move to next and then change state back to 1, the value is lost. I know I can use state to persist values but shouldn't the values be already there without state as I am not unmounting the form?

From the MDN:

display: none turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist).

It means by setting display: none you are removing an element from the DOM which removes the value you have in it. You can consider using visivility: hidden to hide one of your forms, but in this case, other elements won't take the space of the <form>.
Relevant article: Visibility hidden vs display none – What is the difference in CSS ?

So essentially, react removes the element from DOM, which makes it mandatory to use either ref or state to manage the values.
